# jQuery Isotope - How To Sort Alphabetically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Using the isotope library and trying to make it sort alphabetically.  My approach so far is as follows:

```
<div class="sort-block">
  <div name="a">a<div>
  <div name="z">z</div>
  <div name="w">w</div>
</div>
```

And initializing isotope as follows:

```
var $container = $('.chair-block').isotope({
  getSortData: {
    name: '.name' // text from querySelector
}
});
```

But nothing happens with the order.  Any isotope gurus out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would need to see more of your code or make a jsfiddle but you need to have a class of name, not name="a", etc. Also, your isotope container is chair-block, not sort-block. Your isotope code is not correct. As I said, more code to get your help. Are you loading isotope after jQuery, are you using v2?

```
<div class="chair-block">
<div class="item name">a<div>
<div class ="item name">z</div>
<div class ="item name">w</div>
 </div>
```

Javascript

```
 var $container = $('.chair-block');
 $container.isotope({
 itemSelector: '.item',
 masonry: {
    columnWidth: 100
 },
 getSortData: {
    name: '.name' // text from querySelector
 }
 });
```

Here is a [sorting codepen](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/lzCqe)